# Can I use tk.Checkbutton to add variables into a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a python script to delete files by extension (i.e. delete all files that end with `.com`, `.html`, etc.). Currently, I have a tuple and the user must comment out or delete the files he or she wishes to NOT delete. If they want to keep `.com` files for instance, they must comment it out of my script. I would like to create a GUI with tkinter that allows the user to check which extensions they wish to delete.

My objective is to place checked variables into a tuple where I can use the `.endswith()` command to `os.remove()` the files that end with the extensions listed in the tuple.

Without a GUI, this is easy as I just define my tuple in a series of `str` strings. I could just say:

`Files_to_Delete = (".com", ".html")`

But with my attempt at using `tk.Checkbutton()`, I get the error:

*tuple for endswith must only contain str, not StringVar*

I think I'm having a brain fart on how to fix that issue. My button is defined as below:

```
V1 = tk.StringVar()
c1=tk.Checkbutton(root, text=".com", variable=V1, onvalue=".com")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tkinter variables must have their `.get()` method called if you want to find what the value has been set to. Here is an example you can mess around with. I prefer GUIs to be made with OOP, and I hope that doesn't confuse you

```
import tkinter as tk


class OOP:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.com = tk.StringVar()
        self.create_widgets()

    def print_value(self):
        print(self.com)
        print(self.com.get())

    def create_widgets(self):
        tk.Checkbutton(self.win, text=".com", variable=self.com, onvalue=".com").pack()
        tk.Button(self.win, text="Print value", command=self.print_value).pack()


app = OOP()
app.win.mainloop()
```

You can also call `V1.set(".com")` (`self.com.set()` in my example) if you would like to initialize the variable to some value, or just change it's value at all during execution! This example shows that if you omit the `.get()` you will get some weird output like "PY_VAR0" instead of the actual value of the checkbutton

Comment: Hmmm.... I changed my tuple definition from `Files_to_Delete = (V1, V2)` to `Files_to_Delete = (V1.get()), V2.get())` thinking that was brilliant! When I ran my script, it just cleared the entire folder instead of just the files with the extensions defined by the tk.Checkbutton. Maybe I'm not fully understanding how to `str`-ify my tk.Checkbutton variables....

EDIT: After posting, I saw your message updated with OOP example. Unfortunately it is late and I must leave work, but I'll check back in on this first thing in the morning!

Comment: @K.Hess sounds good! When I ran the code it output ".com" or "0" to the terminal, but you can configure the outputs as well. You may even want a `tk.BooleranVar()` depending on the situation.

Comment: After fiddling around, this does indeed work! I've now begun using OOP myself. Thanks!